# How to refresh snapshot in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I what to refresh home page so I create widget called `RefreshWidget` look like this

```
    import 'dart:io';        
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class RefreshWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      // final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> keyRefresh;
      final Widget child;
      final Future Function() onRefresh;
    
      const RefreshWidget({
        Key? key,
        // required this.keyRefresh,
        required this.child,
        required this.onRefresh
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _RefreshWidgetState createState() => _RefreshWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _RefreshWidgetState extends State<RefreshWidget> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
          Platform.isAndroid ? buildAndroidList() : buildIOSList();
    
      Widget buildAndroidList() => RefreshIndicator(
        // key: widget.keyRefresh,
        onRefresh: widget.onRefresh,
        child: widget.child,
      );
    
      Widget buildIOSList() => CustomScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(onRefresh: widget.onRefresh),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: widget.child),
        ],
      );
    }
```

I use it in home and it work just fine like this in side body after check the loading

```
RefreshWidget(
    onRefresh:loadPost,
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: homePosts,
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          int len = snapshot.data?.docs.length??0;
          for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
            _isloaded.add(false);
            userData.add('');
          }
          for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
            if(!_isloaded[i]) {
              getData(snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()['uid'], i);
            }
          }

          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  "No posts yet!",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Palette.textColor,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
         return PageView.builder( ...);
```

loadPost

```
      Future loadPost() async{
        getTheData();
        setState(() {
          homePosts = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy("datePublished", descending: true).where('uid', whereIn: theUserData['following']).snapshots();
        });
      }
```

getTheData

```
/* get data method */
  getTheData() async {
    try {
      if ( uid!= null) {
        var userSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(uid)
            .get();

        /*end*/
        if (userSnap.data() != null) {
          theUserData = userSnap.data()!;
          theUserData['following'].add(uid);
          setState(() {
            _isTheUserLoaded = true;
            homePosts = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy("datePublished", descending: true).where('uid', whereIn: theUserData['following']).snapshots();
          });

        } else
          Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed('/Signup_Login');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
    }
  }
```

---

**The problem**

The post save uid. And I retrieve in the following code (copied from the first code I showed):

```
          int len = snapshot.data?.docs.length??0;
          for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
            _isloaded.add(false);
            userData.add('');
          }
          for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
            if(!_isloaded[i]) {
              getData(snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()['uid'], i);
            }
          }
```

When I unfollow someone `userData` that is a list of user info that posted post that will show in home, is not updated. There for the Home page will show the post with wrong user.

You can find the fill code here on Github: https://github.com/ShathaAldosari01/gp1_7_2022/blob/master/lib/screen/home/TimeLine/home_page.dart

Comment: Demo hear: https://youtu.be/_o-Cjx_-_cY